# Is HTTP header Referer sent when going to a http page from a https page?

Tags: security, http, https, http-headers

After a few tests, I'm starting to reach the conclusion that a browser does not send a Referer HTTP header when one clicks to a http page from a https one.

What security reason is that for? Is is defined somewhere in the standard?

Comment: In any case it is entirely up to the client if Referer should be set or not.

Comment: @Brian : but clients should follow/respect the RFC defining the protocol they are using.

Comment: The current accepted answer is a fine answer, but its the same as @avid's answer which was posted earlier.

Comment: @mikemaccana pffft, by less than a minute... well over 5 years ago... So thanks anyway, but meh ;-)

Answer (score 54, accepted):

The [HTTP RFC](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616.html) states, in section [15.1.3 Encoding Sensitive Information in URI's](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec15.html#sec15.1.3) :

> Clients SHOULD NOT include a Referer
>   header field in a (non-secure) HTTP
>   request if the referring page was
>   transferred with a secure protocol.

So, this is expected / standard behaviour.

Comment: Ok, so how and why google sends referer from https to non-secured sites?

Comment: @confiq because it says `SHOULD NOT`?

Answer (score 21):

Actually it's not that straight forward anymore (2014 onwards), according to this [w3c document on referrer policy](http://w3c.github.io/webappsec/specs/referrer-policy/).

The default behaviour is that browsers will not send referrer information when going from HTTPS to HTTP. However, browsers will send referrer when going from HTTPS to HTTPS.

Also, in HTML5, there is a new meta tag named referrer, that looks like this:

```
<meta name="referrer" content="origin">
```

[New browsers have already implemented this](http://caniuse.com/#search=referrer). So whether or not browsers will send referrer, will depend on this meta tag in the near future. If this meta tag is not included in page's HTML, then browsers will use the default behaviour.

Following are the possible values of content attribute of referrer meta tag:

- no-referrer: Referrer will not be sent, regardless of HTTP or HTTPS
- origin: Only the origin (main) domain will be sent as referrer
- origin-when-crossorigin: Same origin will send full referrer URL and cross origin will send only origin URL as referrer
- no-referrer-when-downgrade: This is the default behaviour when no referrer meta tag is provided on the page.
- unsafe-url: This will always send referrer, regardless of HTTP or HTTPS

Also, there are some legacy attribute values for referrer meta tag. These are no longer recommended, but used in many sites at the moment:

- never: same as no-referrer
- default: same as no-referrer-when-downgrade
- always: same as unsafe-url

I hope this information will be helpful to someone who just found this post after 2014.

Comment: Nice hint. However it does not work on all devices. :( The Chrome in PC/Mac works fine. But Chrome in **Andorid** does NOT work!

Answer (score 17):

Yes, defined in the [standard](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec15.html#sec15.1.3):

> Clients SHOULD NOT include a Referer
>   header field in a (non-secure) HTTP
>   request if the referring page was
>   transferred with a secure protocol

Comment: I'll just add a bit of explanation, https urls often contain sensitive information, such as sessionid, account number, etc. Of course this is bad even over SSL, but its still done... And anyway, HTTPS sessions are usually sensitive applications, there's no reason to needlessly expose that info.

Answer (score 4):

Reason: Sometimes SessionIDs are URL encoded. HTTP Pages can have cross site scripting which steals the session from the HTTPS communication. To prevent this, the referrer is not transmitted on the HTTPS to HTTP transition so that the URL encoded sessin ID can't be stolen.

Comment: op is asking for http -> https, not vice versa.

Comment: @dsas "when one clicks to a http page from a https one" means https -> http, not http -> https.

Comment: @JohnPick you're right of course, I'm not sure how I misread that.

Comment: Is this because referrer is going to contain session ID sometimes?