# How to redirect to the referrer in a filter?

Tags: java, servlets, servlet-filters

how can  I  perform a redirect in filter to the servlet or jsp from which this filter has been called. Actually, I want to check if the user have not permition to see some content, then, while trying to get a forbbiden resourse, the user will stay at the page from where he have tried to get that resource.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the [`doFilter()`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/Filter.html#doFilter%28javax.servlet.ServletRequest,%20javax.servlet.ServletResponse,%20javax.servlet.FilterChain%29) method, you need to cast the obtained [`ServletResponse`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletResponse.html) argument to [`HttpServletResponse`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse.html) and then call the [`sendRedirect()`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse.html#sendRedirect%28java.lang.String%29) method on it. The page where the request originated can be obtained by the `referer` request header (yes, with the legendaric misspelling) which can be obtained by [`HttpServletRequest#getHeader()`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getHeader%28java.lang.String%29) after casting it from the [`ServletRequest`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html) argument.

```
if (userHasPermission) {
    chain.doFilter(request, response);
} else {
    String referrer = ((HttpServletRequest) request).getHeader("referer");
    ((HttpServletResponse) response).sendRedirect(referrer);
}
```

Please note that the referrer is a **client-controlled value** and thus this can be spoofed or even removed. You'd like to add conditional checks on the obtained value and when absent or invalid, redirect to the main page instead or somewhere else.

#### See also:

- [Our `servlet-filters` wiki page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlet-filters/info) (you can get this page by putting your mouse above the tag below the question until a popbox shows and then click the *info* link on the popbox)

Comment: no, you give the static name of page to redirect, I want to get to know the page(servlet) from which I have got to this filter and redirect to that page

Comment: but according to this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1361705/is-http-header-referer-sent-when-going-to-a-http-page-from-a-https-page ((HttpServletRequest) request).getHeader("referer") will not return anything.

Comment: It will indeed be omitted when a switch from HTTPS to HTTP is made. Exactly as the quesiton/answer which you linked yourself says :) Are you in your code also switching from HTTPS to HTTP then? You'd need to pass the current request URI as a request parameter instead. All with all, I have to admit that the functional requirement as stated in your question makes in real world very little sense. I'd really rethink/reconsider the decision to let your webapp behave that way. I'd rather show a 401 unauthorized or 403 forbidden error page like as every other decent webapp.

Comment: I haven't switched from HTTPS to HTTP in code but the ((HttpServletRequest) request).getHeader("referer") always return null. in any case, thanks very much

Comment: Then it's your webbrowser or plugins or some client platform specific software which has hidden it. For example some Norton software has a setting to spoof/hide the HTTP referrer. Nothing to do against from the server side on.