# How can I get https referrer URL

Tags: c#, https, referrer

I am using the code `HttpContext.Current.Request.UrlReferer ?? (Object)).ToString()` in my project to get the referrer URL from my hosted application.

When I am redirecting from an HTTP page then I am able to get the URL, but if I'm redirecting from an HTTPS page then I am getting a null value, how can I get UrlReferrer  working for HTTPS?

Comment: @ChaitanyaGadkari don't use `inline code` to highlight random terms.

Comment: The referrer doesn't get sent, as explained in [Is HTTP header Referer sent when going to a http page from a https page?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1361705/is-http-header-referer-sent-when-going-to-a-http-page-from-a-https-page). You shouldn't build your application logic on the referrer anyway, because certain browsers, users or plugins can disable referrers altogether. Explain the problem you are trying to solve by using the referrer; perhaps there's a better solution for it.

Answer (score 2):

That behavior is by design.  URLReferrer header should not be sent for SSL requests.  See:

http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec15.html#sec15.1.3

"**Clients SHOULD NOT include a Referer header field in a (non-secure)   HTTP request if the referring page was transferred with a secure   protocol.**"

So, in your case HttpContext.Current.Request.UrlReferrer would be null and If information about the urlreferrer isn't sent, there really isn't much you can do, may be you could just use  HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Host

Comment: Thank you @StackTrace Current will also not work

Comment: we are now securing the other site as well, so that there wont be any communication issues. Thanks for your help :)