# App Engine session security issues

Tags: java, security, google-app-engine, session

I am storing user state (logged in / user id) in sessions on app engine.  Is it possible for users that know other users UserId to manipulate their cookies and login as other users.

What steps should I take to prevent this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible for one user to directly access data from another user.  However, there are ways for one user to steal the login session of another user.  But this isn't GAE specific.

See:

1. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Session_hijacking
2. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery (CSRF)

Hijacking can easily occur on an open wifi hotspot.  A common solution is to host your site with [SSL](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/ssl).

CSRF happens when a user is logged into your website and has a malicious website open in the same browser.  There are various ways to protect against this.  A common solution is to include a random [validation token](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/198520/how-to-best-prevent-csrf-attacks-in-a-gae-app) in HTML forms.  Also, set HTTP response [header](http://blog.whitehatsec.com/x-frame-options/): `X-Frame-Options: sameorigin` and check request header `X-Requested-With` isn't equal to "XMLHttpRequest" for non-ajax hits.

XSS can be used to make these attacks more effective, so protect against it too.

For these types of attacks in general, make your user [sessions expire](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Session_Timeout) quickly.

Answer (score 1):

I am not a security expert. But what I have learned:

- use HTTPS
- do not use frames
- use a new CSRF token in your forms for every request
- and save your state  in the datastore instead of using a session cookie store.